# Php and HTML validations

Tags: php, html, validation

```
 <form name="addEvent" id="addEvent" action="appointment.php" onsubmit="" method="POST">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Add Calendar Event:</legend><br>
            <label>Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="nitle" name="title" value="" maxlength="255"><span id="name1"></span><br><br>

            <label>Date</label>
                <select id="month" name="month">
                    <option value="0">Month</option>
                    <option value="1">January</option>
                    <option value="2">February</option>
                    <option value="3">March</option>
                    <option value="4">April</option>
                    <option value="5">May</option>
                    <option value="6">June</option>
                    <option value="7">July</option>
                    <option value="8">August</option>
                    <option value="9">September</option>
                    <option value="10">October</option>
                    <option value="11">November</option>
                    <option value="12">December</option> &nbsp;
                </select>
                <select id="day" name="day">
                    <option value="0">Date</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                    <option value="7">7</option>
                    <option value="8">8</option>
                    <option value="9">9</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                    <option value="11">11</option>
                    <option value="12">12</option>
                    <option value="13">13</option>
                    <option value="14">14</option>
                    <option value="15">15</option>
                    <option value="16">16</option>
                    <option value="17">17</option>
                    <option value="18">18</option>
                    <option value="19">19</option>
                    <option value="20">20</option>
                    <option value="21">21</option>
                    <option value="22">22</option>
                    <option value="23">23</option>
                    <option value="24">24</option> 
                    <option value="25">25</option>
                    <option value="26">26</option>
                    <option value="27">27</option>
                    <option value="28">28</option>
                    <option value="29">29</option>
                    <option value="30">30</option>
                    <option value="31">31</option> 
                </select>
                <select id="year" name="year">
                    <option value="0">Year</option>
                    <option value="2015">2015</option>
                    <option value="2016">2016</option>
                </select><span id="year1"></span><span id="date1"></span><br><br>
            <label>Start Time</label>
                <input type="text" id="starttime" name="starttime" value="" placeholder="HH:MM" maxlength="7" >
            <br>

            <label>Contact E-mail</label>
                <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="email@domain.com" maxlength="80"><span id="email1"></span><br><br><br>
            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Add Event">&nbsp; &nbsp;
            <input type="reset" id="reset" value="Reset Fields">
    </fieldset> 
  </form>
```

php external.... don't want to put with html file...

```
<?php

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $month = $_POST['month'];
    $day = $_POST['day'];
    $year = $_POST['year'];
    $starttime = $_POST['starttime'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];



    if (strlen($name) < 3) {
        echo '* Name must be at least 3 characters long' . '<br>';
        }

    if ($month == 0) {
        echo '* Month must be chosen' . '<br>';
        }
    if ($day == 0) {
        echo '* Day must be chosen' . '<br>';
        }
    if ($year != 2016) {
        echo '* Year must be 2016' . '<br>';
        }
    if ($month == 2 && $day == 30) {
        echo '* Feb 30th is an invalid date' . '<br>';
        }
    if ($month == 2 && $day == 31) {
        echo '* Feb 31st is an invalid date' . '<br>';
        }
    if (empty($starttime)) {
        echo '* Must input valid  Appointment Time' . '<br>';
        }

    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        echo '* Must input valid email address' . '<br>';
        }
    else {
        echo '<br>' . 'Submission Successful!' . '<br>';
        }


?>
```

is there away anyone can test and see if this works everytime I test it out it gives me Cannot POST /appointment.php  (I'm not too good at php and i would like to keep the syntax the same as i can read it easier and understand what it is doing)  also am i connecting it properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first mistake is your html control name is `title` and in php you are trying to get `name` so first please change that as shown in below.

`$name = $_POST['name'];` replace your this code with below code.

$name = $_POST['title'];
after that you will get message as you set 
Submission Successful!

Comment: I'm still getting the CANNOT POST/appointment.php   but its working for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
<input type="text" id="nitle" name="title" value="" maxlength="255">
```

to

```
<input type="text" id="title" name="title" value="" maxlength="255">
```

And on **appointment.php** change

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
```

to

```
$name = $_POST['title'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems good to me except this one in appointment.php.

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
```

to

> $name = $_POST['title'];

As, your textbox accepting name value has name 'title'.

> And, make sure your both files html and php (appointment.php) are in
>   the same path.

Hope, it helps

Comment: what do you mean by path?? honestly this is my first time with php on my computer and usually i'm on a vm which has everything previously installed i'm not sure if i have apache sql or php activated and idk how but i keep getting the cannot post to appointment.php

Comment: Are both files in the same folder ?

Comment: And also, add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the begining of the php file to see for the actual error.

Comment: And, Can I know, where are you executing these files (Server/localhost server)? Because, you may be aware that php needs to be run in a server only.

Comment: all files are in the same folder and localhost i believe

Comment: Okay, Are you running any `server (i.e XAMPP,WAMP etc)` to run your php files ?